# transfer from dma to disk

Tags: file, buffer, transfer, dma

I receive packets from dma in streaming mode (32 packets per call), I need to copy them to a file. When all dma buffer is full I use memcpy to take dma buffer to another ram buffer and another thread copy it to the file. But I realised memcpy decreases my speed (about 100MB/sn). It has to be upper 200MB/sn. My system is windows.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `memcpy` is unlikely to decrease your speed. Why do you think it does? If you remove the `memcpy`, and just write garbage, how fast is that?

Comment: when i write garbage it is very fast. but today i realised that the problem may be VirtualAlloc. Because  when the source parameter of memcpy is buffer being allocated by VirtualAlloc is slow.

Comment: Why are you even using `VirtualAlloc`? That's not the usual memory allocation function.

Comment: Because of memory fragmentation. I solved the problem, PAGE_NOCACHE parameter was the reason. Now I am looking a way to write to file fastly , It never ends :). Thank you.